# Generate .pb file without using protoc in golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-go

I'm trying to generate `.pb.go` file using `service.proto` as file input in Go.

Is there a way to do it without using `protoc` binary (like directly using package `github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`)?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `detail.proto` like this:

```
message AppDetails {
   optional string version = 4;
}
```

You can parse it into a message like this:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
   "github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc/protoparse"
   "github.com/jhump/protoreflect/dynamic"
)

func parse(file, msg string) (*dynamic.Message, error) {
   var p protoparse.Parser
   fd, err := p.ParseFiles(file)
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
   md := fd[0].FindMessage(msg)
   return dynamic.NewMessage(md), nil
}

func main() {
   b := []byte("\"\vhello world")
   m, err := parse("detail.proto", "AppDetails")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   if err := proto.Unmarshal(b, m); err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   fmt.Println(m) // version:"hello world"
}
```

However you may notice, this package is still using the old Protobuf V1. I did
find a Pull Request for V2:

https://github.com/jhump/protoreflect/pull/354

Comment: I simply want to bypass the use of `protoc` and directly use the underlying APIs of `protoc-gen-go` to generate the `.pb.go` files using go code.

Comment: Actually I want to convert protobuf messages to json using go. I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65371394) but it relies on `protoc` binary which I can't use in my code (due to limitations on my part)

Comment: You are not getting what I'm asking here. I don't want any external library. I'm allowed to only use official libraries from google for my project. I'm sorry if I sounded rude. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: This way is much better than I'm doing currently, but I think this does not support proto3 syntax. For now I'm generating descriptor set out using the protoc binary and reading the generated pb file. This approach works for every version of proto syntax.